# Restrict user from playing file when download is not fully completed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest for downloading audio, video and image files from a server.

If the download is not completed fully, I want to restrict the user from play that file.

Is there any way that I can restrict those file which are currently downloading?

Comment: I am just checked whether file exists or not before playing the file.

Comment: Disable/Hide the button to play unless download is complete. What is the big deal here ?

Comment: actually downloading is going on in one view and playing is on another tab view

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a model of "Files" and keep track of the state yourself.
The library you're using doesn't provide a high level abstraction of file state.

If you need more specific help, tell us how you're handling files now. Does your "other tab view" simply display files on a filesystem/OS level?

Answer (score 1):

> - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

In This delegate trigger notification, which calls when downloading finished. Make your play button hide until you receive notification from Request finished delegate. Hope it'll help.